# Exponential distribution variance

Tags: probability

> The loss L due to a boat accident is exponentially distributed. Boat
>   insurance policy A covers up to 1 unit for each loss. Boat insurance
>   policy B covers up to 2 units for each loss. The probability that a
>   loss is fully covered under policy B is 1.9 times the probability that
>   it is fully covered under policy A. Calculate the variance of L.

My work:

Let L = loss ~ exp($\lambda$)

Then, 
$P(L \leq 1) * 1.9 = P(L \leq 2)\\
 1.9*(1-e^{-\lambda)} = 1-e^{-2\lambda}
$

I need to find $\lambda$ as variance of exponential is $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$, but I am not sure how to solve this? Is there a trick?

(Finan exam p 34.24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=e^{-\lambda}$. The $(1.9)(1-t)=1-t^{2}$. We can write this as $t^{2}-(1.9)t+(0.9)=0$. Hence $t =\frac {1.9 \pm \sqrt {(1.9)^{2}-3.6}} 2$. Check that the positive sign gives $t=1$ which gives the unacceptable value $\lambda =0$. Thus $t =\frac {1.9 - \sqrt {(1.9)^{2}-3.6}} 2=0.9$.  Finally $\lambda =-\ln t$.